# Ways to match list items with linq sql objects

Tags: c#, linq, linq-to-sql

I have a List and I want to see if any of these strings are in any of 3 fields of a single sql record using linq to sql.

```
   ListA<strings>;
   var found=db.People.Where(p=>p.field1 field 2 or field 3 is in ListA). Select this person
```

Answer (score 2):

```
var found = db.People.Where(p=>ListA.Contains(p.field1) || ListA.Contains(p.field2) || ListA.Contains(p.field3));
```

Answer (score 1):

Use this code:

```
ListA<strings>;
var found=db.People.Where(p=>
  ListA.Contains(p.field1) || ListaA.Contains(p.field2) 
  || ListaA.Contains(p.field3));
```

Please, be aware that this will take all the records from the DB and test the condition on the application side.

EDIT: this is just the same code of the other answer, but includes a note on how it works, so I don't delete it. (Changed because of @Adrian lftode comment)

Comment: what kind of C# are you using?

Comment: I wrote or instead of ||. That's an error of course. But I left "Select this person" as is from the original message, as I suppose that's some kind of "pseudo-code".

Comment: the problem with your answer is that is not correct because of the syntax. Think that a very new with C# will get confused when is seeing this

Comment: I don't think it's true that it will take all the records from the DB and compare them in the aplpication. In my experience, LINQ to SQL is smart enough to convert "Contains" to "IN" and "||" to "OR" in TSQL.

Comment: @JotaBe, I removed my downvote, you don't have to delete your answer.. I guess